# Office 365/outlook is creating p/paragraph between tables and make additional gap on forward message

Tags: email, outlook, office365, html-email, signature

email sending from web or thunderbird client is fine but if i try forward message from outlook.. it get messy by additional gap like `p.MsoNorma` or other strange things

[image: preview]
[image: gap]

here is head:

```
<HTML lang="en">
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Email Signature</TITLE>
    
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
        <style type="text/css">
        /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
          body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
          table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
          img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

          table, tr, td {
            border-collapse: collapse!important;
             }

            tr {
                font-size:0px!important;
                line-height:0px!important;
            }
            td p.MsoNormal {
                margin: 0.1px!important;
                margin-top: 0.1px!important;
                margin-bottom: 0.1px!important;
            }

            p{
                margin-top: 0px!important;
                margin-bottom: 0px!important;
              }
          /* RESET STYLES */
          img { border: 0; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
          table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
          /* body { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; } */
          
          /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
          a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
          }    
    </HEAD>
```

sample body of message

```
    <body>

                <table width="375" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container" style="background-color:#e1e1e1;border-spacing: 0 !important; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                 <tr>
                   <td width="56" class="mobile" align="left" valign="top" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style=" PADDING: 0px!important; MARGIN-TOP: 0px!important; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px!important;">
                        <a href="/" target="_blank" >
                            <img border="0" width="56" height="auto" src="here should be image"  style="width: 56px;  height: auto; display: block;">
                        </a>
                    </p>
                   </td>
                   <td width="295" class="mobile" align="left" valign="top" style="vertical-align: middle; font-size:14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 75%;">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style=" PADDING: 0px!important; MARGIN-TOP: 0px!important; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px!important;">
                        <strong><span style="FONT-SIZE: 16px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; color:#000000; ">random text</span></strong>
                        <br><span style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 11px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; color:#000000;">another text</span>    
                    </p>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                
               </table>
               <table width="375" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container" style="background-color:#e1e1e1;border-spacing: 0 !important; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                <tr>
                  <td width="56" class="mobile" align="left" valign="top">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style=" PADDING: 0px!important; MARGIN-TOP: 0px!important; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px!important;">
                    </p>
                  </td>
                  <td align="left" width="295" valign="top" style="font-size:14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 75%;">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style=" PADDING: 0px!important; MARGIN-TOP: 0px!important; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px!important;">  <span style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 11px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial;color:#000000;"><strong>m: </strong><font color="black">+48 333 333 333</font></span><br>
                        <span class="show" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 11px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; color:#000000;"><strong>e: </strong><font color="black">my@email.com</font></span>
                    </p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

</body>
```

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,

I tried remove `margins`, add `display block` to `td`, `vertical-align: middle` etc

Answer (score 0):

Trying to maintain styles on forwarding is essentially impossible because email clients will change your code when they get it.

You can, however, experiment and try different approaches to see what happens--there's just no guarantees.

For Outlook, you cannot get past the fact that it renders emails as if they're for print, and thus kills all responsive behaviour, and forces the layout into a static desktop layout.

You could try creating the grey background on another table behind these ones, to keep the grey consistent.

I.e.

```
<table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:#e1e1e1;border-spacing: 0 !important; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      ..other tables
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it's not helps
`
<table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:#e1e1e1;border-spacing: 0 !important; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      ..other tables
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
`